# First digits of extremely large binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, decimal-expansion

Can the first digits of a binomial coeffecient

$$\binom{n}{k}$$

be calculated, if n and k are very large numbers ?

For example

Calculate the first ten digits of

$$\binom{10^{85}}{10^{23}}$$

Any ideas ?

Comment: By "first ten," you mean the ten most significant digits, right?  (That's what I think you mean, but I wanted to make sure--the least significant digits are much easier to calculate.)  Are the very large numbers always powers of ten?

Comment: No, this was only an example. And yes, I mean the most significant digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to compute fractional part $\log_{10} \binom{10^{85}}{10^{23}}$, exponentiate and retain the desired number of first significant digits.

Getting rid of integer part allows to avoid scale overflow problems.

Here is the computation of first 20 significant digits in *Mathematica*:

```
In[108]:= Block[{n = 10^83, k = 10^23},
 IntegerPart[
  10^20 (FractionalPart[(LogGamma[n + 1`100] - 
         LogGamma[n - k + 1`100] - LogGamma[k + 1`100])/Log[10]] // 
     Exp)]
 ]

Out[108]= 269878514735170511101
```

Comment: Very well programmed!

Comment: I thought about stirling, but did not consider that the number becomes small enough to calculate it with high precision.

Comment: Does Mathematica compute `LogGamma` with enough precision that the fractional part is reliable for this?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, _Mathematica_'s result for $\log\Gamma$ may be of lower precision that its argument, but all the significant digits of the result are correct.

Comment: @user40314: So `LogGamma[10^83+1]` gives a result to 106 significant digits? Otherwise there won't be 20 significant digits in the fractional part ....

Comment: @HenningMakholm Result of evaluation of `LogGamma[10^83 + 1`100]` has 183 significant decimal digits